# API21 setButtonTintList on CheckBox

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-checkbox

I am trying to use the new Android Lollipop API `setButtonTintList()` to programmatically apply colors to android `CheckBox`es.

I have set the following basic `ColorStateList` in `checkbox_color.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true"
          android:color="@color/red" />

    <item android:state_checked="false"
          android:color="@color/green" />

</selector>
```

On a specific `Button` click in my app I inflate a new layout that contains a `CheckBox` into my main layout (`mLayoutTotalItemRow`) via:

```
View itemRow = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row_add_purchase, mLayoutTotalItemRow, false);
```

After the inflation, I want to apply `checkbox_color.xml` to the new `CheckBox` via (the reason I want to do this in code rather than xml is that I want to set different colors depending on some variables):

```
mCheckBoxEnabled.setButtonTintList(mContext.getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.checkbox_color));
```

Now a strange thing happens, when the `CheckBox` is first created, it is red (hence `state_checked="true"`. As soon as I uncheck it, it is green (`state_chacked="false"`). But when I check it again now, it changes to ticked but it stays green! Hence somehow the internal view state is not changing to "checked".

My checkbox xml:

```
   <CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/cb_item_enabled"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/key_line_1_minus_checkbox_margin"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/key_line_2_minus_key_line_1_minus_checkbox"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:checked="true"/>
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: have you used `android:duplicateParentState` ?

Comment: I have not. I just tried adding it to my checkbox but the result is the same! For reference, I added the xml for the checkbox to the question.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this on a Nexus device running Android 5.0.1. What device are you testing this on?

Comment: I am using a Nexus 6 running Android 5.0.1... Maybe the problem lies elsewhere, I will setup a new blank project with a single checkbox and try again. Will report back!

Comment: Ok, I created a blank project and added nothing but a CheckBox widget in the MainActivity's layout. This time I did not set checked="true". In the activity's onCreate I then used setButtonTintList as above. Now the effect is inverted, the checkbox is green at first and when I click it, it turns red and stays red no matter what I do.

Comment: What version of the Android SDK Build-tools package are you using? Latest 21.1.2? Are you using appcompat-v7?

Comment: I am using the latest 21.1.2. My project is using appcompat-v7 but in the blank project with only the checkbox I tried with and without appcompat-v7, same result!

Comment: Same issue here! Did you find somethings?

Comment: Not sure if it helps but what if you try to use XML attribute? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html#attr_android:buttonTint

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not yet found a solution. XML attribute won't help me, I need to set this programmatically!

Answer (score 6):

I have reported the bug to the Android project.  [Issue 157166](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=157166)
**Fix for the next release 5.1**

> This is fixed in 5.1, which isn't *quite* released yet.
>
> Status: FutureRelease

**EDIT 10.03.2015**

> Released in 5.1.

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin:

```
val iconsColorStates = ColorStateList(arrayOf(intArrayOf(-android.R.attr.state_selected),
                intArrayOf(android.R.attr.state_selected)),
                intArrayOf(color, color))

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    buttonTintList = iconsColorStates
} else {
    (this as TintableCompoundButton).supportButtonTintList = iconsColorStates
}
```